# OxyPlot WPF Muliple LinearBarSeries with same X-Axis Values

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I currently have the need to be able to display multiple bars that may have the same X-Axis value. I used the WPF LinearBarSeries example in the source code.

The issue I am having is if the series with the smaller Y value is selected first, the series with the bigger Y value hides the smaller one. If I select the series with the bigger Y value first and then the smaller Y value, they both are displayed.

I am putting a small border around my bars to make them more readable.

Bigger First

[image: Bigger Y Value First]

Smaller First
[image: Smaller Y Value First]

Admittedly, I'm not an expert with OxyPlot and I haven't done a whole lot of charting in the past. Is there a better approach I should be taking? Maybe a different Series to use?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the way to display LinearBarSeries  side by side either. I finally used the RectangleBarSeries where the bar is defined between two points x,y, and so you can manually define an offset between them.

```
var serie = new RectangleBarSeries { Title = "Example"};
serie.Items.Add(new RectangleBarItem(x1, 0, x2, y2));
```